# Can i display different static block for different products?

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9.1

I want to know if we are able to select different for different products.
So, i can not place for product x only the field 1 and 2 ("30 Tage.." und kostenfreie...") of static block  and for product y the field 3 and 4 of static block? Please Help Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a attribute with text field & set name as `product_block_identfier`, Insert the static block identifier value in this field.

Now call static block on `view.phtml` file

```
getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_product->getProductBlockIdentfier())->toHtml() ?>
```

`$_product->getProductBlockIdentfier()` this will get the block id from the product attribute `product_block_identfier`

Hope this will work for you!